# CleverCSS replacement

Tags: python, css, less, clevercss

Hello I am looking into cleverCSS to use in my python App. I am looking at the Python package site and its latest version is from 2007. I was wondering if someone has continued work on a similar project? I considered using LESS but was drawn more toward clever because of it being python.

Answer (score 7):

Unless there's a good reason that you need to use a Python-based one, I would recommend that you use the best tool for the job. I don't particularly like the way that LESS and SASS use Ruby—I'd far prefer Python—but if that's what they use, then that's what they use and I'm not going to complain too bitterly. I would only use an inferior one like CleverCSS in favour of a superior one if I was needing to use it from Python code and the performance difference was significant enough in comparison to executing the script. And that's a far less common problem.

As for options, I am of the opinion that [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) is the best one available; in various things it's just better than LESS and SASS (not least of which is its transparent function/mixin calls—so that you can have, for example, a `border-radius` mixin which will take the valid CSS `border-radius: 2px;` and add to it any prefixes you feel like). And it's written in Javascript rather than Ruby which is a positive :-)

Comment: Thanks I will Look into that. Yea I would just prefer it to be Python because everything else in the stack is and would be easy to fit into my existing script that builds the stylesheets for production.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` isn't hard to use. (The fact that you'd need Node would be far more important.) I would recommend against using CleverCSS *just* because it's Python, and use the best tool, whatever you decide that may be&mdash;I fancy you'll spend more time working with stylesheets than writing the build script.

Comment: It's no problem when you work alone but when you are in a group, everyone has to install this stuff on their testing setup. And as you can imagine you may have a hard time convincing your people.

Comment: @dAnjou: surely that's going to be a problem whatever you use? (install binaries, install Python modules, same problem.) The simple solution for that is to have a collected location where every such thing is kept. At my workplace, that's done as an "SDKs" repository.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked it back in 2010 http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/jun/17/clevercss-reloaded/

And then did a total rewrite http://jaredforsyth.com/projects/clevercss2/

Both are on github, feel free to fork

Comment: CleverCSS2 seems from 2010, while it got a little touch-up at 2012. – And I don’t like that it uses grave accent characters (“backticks”) in it’s syntax without alternatives.